# Optimising MySQL Database Indexes InnoDB

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, innodb

I have been Googleling for hours now and I haven't quite figured out how indexes work, because there are so many mixed answers available.

Let's say I have an query 1:

```
SELECT subid, subid2 FROM clicks WHERE wid=100 AND uid=123 AND time >= 1387886885
```

And a query 2:

```
SELECT subid, subid2 FROM clicks WHERE fid=100 AND time >= 1387886885 AND uid=123
```

1) How should I place indexes here? Should I use multi column index or single column indexes?

2) I found an answer on stackoverflow that suggested adding indexes to subid and subid2 also, should I do that? If not, under what circumstances would one do that?

Comment: if you have a lot (billions) of clicks, and you run this query relatively often, you could think of partitionning depending on the time column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How should I place indexes here? Should I use multi column index or
>   single column indexes?

You should create compound indexes (read as multi column indexes) because these have better index selectivity

> I found an answer on stackoverflow that suggested adding indexes to
>   subid and subid2 also, should I do that? If not, under what
>   circumstances would one do that?

I think you mean an covering index. An covering index is very fast for selecting data because all data can be read from the index data without accessing the table data..

**Query 1**

```
SELECT subid, subid2 FROM clicks WHERE wid=100 AND uid=123 AND time >= 1387886885
```

Needs this index

```
INDEX(wid, uid, time)
```

or this covering index

```
INDEX(wid, uid, time, subid, subid2)
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT subid, subid2 FROM clicks WHERE fid=100 AND time >= 1387886885 AND uid=123
```

Needs this index

```
INDEX(fid, uid, time)
```

or this covering index

```
INDEX(fid, uid, time, subid, subid2)
```

Comment: Maybe I should use a covering index such as (uid,time,subid,subid2) to avoid creating almost identical indexes?
There's actually fid, wid and yid so I would need 3 almost identical indexes.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link of trying to simplify indexes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460138/mysql-index-usage-query-optimization/20462042#20462042)  From a beginner perspective, the simple example of the original post and explaining how the index correlates to what they were looking for might help.

So, in your scenario, I would have one index based on

( wid, uid, time )

(not sure if the wid vs fid was just a type-o)

An index should be done with a basis of what your most common querying components may be asking for... typically some ID, or User basis, maybe date ranges.  But per the link example, get your criteria with the field that will be most precise to the front of the list of indexed fields.