# Optimize SQL query with many joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to troubleshoot a query that we need to run for internal purposes. This query is not part of an application so it doesn't have to be all that efficient, but I'd like it to be as fast as possible so that we can get the data set we need to move forward.

The first issue I came about was that the query was being stuck in the Statistics status. That was remedied by adding the following to our mySQL configuration...

```
optimizer_search_depth = 0
```

Now the query goes right into 'Copying data to tmp table', which has been happening for more than 5 minutes so far. Our server is extremely powerful, and we have 128GB of RAM, so I don't believe it is a resource issue at all. I do believe that the query itself may have to be optimized a bit, and that's what I'd like guidance on if at all possible.

The results of the "EXPLAIN SELECT" [can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApQvi.jpg). Before running the EXPLAIN SELECT, I performed "ANALYZE" on all of the tables in this database (created for the purpose of this one-time query).

The query itself is here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      IAN.sku,
      IAN.notes,
      Parts.partterminologyname,
      BaseVehicle.YearID,
      Make.MakeName,
      Model.modelname,
      SubModel.SubModelName,
      CONCAT(EngineBase.Cylinders, ' Cyl ', EngineBase.Liter, 'L') as engine,
      Positions.position,
      BedLength.BedLength,
      BedLength.BedLengthMetric,
      BedType.BedTypeName,
      BodyNumDoors.BodyNumDoors,
      BodyType.BodyTypeName,
      FrontBrakeType.BrakeTypeName,
      RearBrakeType.BrakeTypeName,
      BrakeSystem.BrakeSystemName,
      BrakeABS.BrakeABSName,
      DriveType.DriveTypeName,
      EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationName,
      EngineVIN.EngineVINName,
      Valves.ValvesPerEngine,
      EngineBase.Liter,
      EngineBase.CC,
      EngineBase.CID,
      EngineBase.Cylinders,
      EngineBase.BlockType,
      EngineBase.EngBoreIn,
      EngineBase.EngBoreMetric,
      EngineBase.EngStrokeIn,
      EngineBase.EngStrokeMetric,
      FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeName,
      FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeName,
      FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeName,
      FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignName,
      Aspiration.AspirationName,
      CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeName,
      FuelType.FuelTypeName,
      IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeName,
      EngineMfr.MfrName,
      EngineVersion.EngineVersion,
      PowerOutput.HorsePower,
      PowerOutput.KilowattPower,
      MfrBodyCode.MfrBodyCodeName,
      SpringType.SpringTypeName,
      SteeringType.SteeringTypeName,
      SteeringSystem.SteeringSystemName,
      TransmissionType.TransmissionTypeName,
      TransmissionNumSpeeds.TransmissionNumSpeeds,
      TransmissionMfrCode.TransmissionMfrCode,
      TransElecControlled.ElecControlled,
      TransmissionMfr.MfrName,
      WheelBase.WheelBase,
      WheelBase.WheelBaseMetric
   FROM
      Import_AcesApplication_New IAN
         INNER JOIN BaseVehicle 
            ON IAN.base_vehicle_id = BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
            INNER JOIN Make 
               ON BaseVehicle.MakeID = Make.MakeID
            INNER JOIN Model 
               ON BaseVehicle.ModelID = Model.ModelID
         INNER JOIN Positions 
            ON IAN.position_id = Positions.PositionID
         INNER JOIN Parts 
            ON IAN.part_type_id = Parts.PartTerminologyID
         INNER JOIN Vehicle 
            ON IAN.base_vehicle_id = Vehicle.BaseVehicleID
            INNER JOIN SubModel 
               ON Vehicle.SubModelID = SubModel.SubModelID
            INNER JOIN VehicleConfig 
               ON Vehicle.VehicleID = VehicleConfig.VehicleID
               INNER JOIN EngineConfig 
                  ON VehicleConfig.EngineConfigID = EngineConfig.EngineConfigID
                  INNER JOIN EngineBase 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineBaseID = EngineBase.EngineBaseID
                  INNER JOIN EngineDesignation 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineDesignationID = EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationID
                  INNER JOIN EngineVIN 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineVINID = EngineVIN.EngineVINID
                  INNER JOIN Valves 
                     ON EngineConfig.ValvesID = Valves.Valvesid
                  INNER JOIN FuelDeliveryConfig 
                     ON EngineConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID = FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID
                     INNER JOIN FuelDeliveryType 
                        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryTypeID = FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeID
                     INNER JOIN FuelDeliverySubType 
                        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliverySubTypeID = FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeID
                     INNER JOIN FuelSystemControlType 
                        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemControlTypeID = FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeID
                     INNER JOIN FuelSystemDesign 
                        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemDesignID = FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignID
                  INNER JOIN Aspiration 
                     ON EngineConfig.AspirationID = Aspiration.AspirationID
                  INNER JOIN CylinderHeadType 
                     ON EngineConfig.CylinderHeadTypeID = CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeID
                  INNER JOIN FuelType 
                     ON EngineConfig.FuelTypeID = FuelType.FuelTypeID
                  INNER JOIN IgnitionSystemType 
                     ON  EngineConfig.IgnitionSystemTypeID = IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeID
                  INNER JOIN Mfr EngineMfr 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineMfrID = EngineMfr.MfrID
                  INNER JOIN EngineVersion 
                     ON EngineConfig.EngineVersionID = EngineVersion.EngineVersionID
                  INNER JOIN PowerOutput 
                     ON EngineConfig.PowerOutputId = PowerOutput.PowerOutputId
               INNER JOIN BedConfig 
                  ON VehicleConfig.BedConfigID = BedConfig.BedConfigID
                  INNER JOIN BedLength 
                     ON BedConfig.BedLengthID = BedLength.BedLengthID
                  INNER JOIN BedType 
                     ON BedConfig.BedTypeID = BedType.BedTypeID
               INNER JOIN BodyStyleConfig 
                  ON VehicleConfig.BodyStyleConfigID = BodyStyleConfig.BodyStyleConfigID
                  INNER JOIN BodyNumDoors 
                     ON BodyStyleConfig.BodyNumDoorsID = BodyNumDoors.BodyNumDoorsID
                  INNER JOIN BodyType 
                     ON BodyStyleConfig.BodyTypeID = BodyType.BodyTypeID
               INNER JOIN BrakeConfig 
                  ON VehicleConfig.BrakeConfigID = BrakeConfig.BrakeConfigID
                  INNER JOIN BrakeType FrontBrakeType 
                     ON BrakeConfig.FrontBrakeTypeID = FrontBrakeType.BrakeTypeID
                  INNER JOIN BrakeType RearBrakeType 
                     ON BrakeConfig.RearBrakeTypeID = RearBrakeType.BrakeTypeID
                  INNER JOIN BrakeSystem 
                     ON BrakeConfig.BrakeSystemID = BrakeSystem.BrakeSystemID
                  INNER JOIN BrakeABS 
                     ON BrakeConfig.BrakeABSID = BrakeABS.BrakeABSID
               INNER JOIN DriveType 
                  ON VehicleConfig.DriveTypeID = DriveType.DriveTypeID
               INNER JOIN MfrBodyCode 
                  ON VehicleConfig.MfrBodyCodeID = MfrBodyCode.MfrBodyCodeID
               INNER JOIN SpringType 
                  ON VehicleConfig.SpringTypeConfigID = SpringType.SpringTypeID
               INNER JOIN SteeringConfig 
                  ON VehicleConfig.SteeringConfigID = SteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID
                  INNER JOIN SteeringType 
                     ON SteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID = SteeringType.SteeringTypeID
                  INNER JOIN SteeringSystem 
                     ON SteeringConfig.SteeringSystemID = SteeringSystem.SteeringSystemID
               INNER JOIN Transmission 
                  ON VehicleConfig.TransmissionID = Transmission.TransmissionID
                  INNER JOIN TransmissionBase 
                     ON Transmission.TransmissionBaseID = TransmissionBase.TransmissionBaseID
                     INNER JOIN TransmissionType 
                        ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionTypeID = TransmissionType.TransmissionTypeID
                     INNER JOIN TransmissionNumSpeeds 
                        ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionNumSpeedsID = TransmissionNumSpeeds.TransmissionNumSpeedsID
                     INNER JOIN TransmissionControlType 
                        ON TransmissionBase.TransmissionControlTypeID = TransmissionControlType.TransmissionControlTypeID
                  INNER JOIN TransmissionMfrCode 
                     ON Transmission.TransmissionMfrCodeID = TransmissionMfrCode.TransmissionMfrCodeID
                  INNER JOIN ElecControlled TransElecControlled 
                     ON Transmission.TransmissionElecControlledID = TransElecControlled.ElecControlledID
                  INNER JOIN Mfr TransmissionMfr 
                     ON Transmission.TransmissionMfrID = TransmissionMfr.MfrID
               INNER JOIN WheelBase 
                  ON VehicleConfig.WheelbaseID = WheelBase.WheelBaseID
   LIMIT 
      0,10
```

There are many, main JOINS in the query because of the way that the database was setup. The database is a standard in our industry and isn't something I would like to change up. It should be noted that this query will probably only be run once every few months so while optimizing it is important, it does NOT have to be super efficient. The only expectation of the end result is that we're not waiting days and days for the data to be ready.

I appreciate any guidance on this, and apologize if this is a bit much to ask for advice on.

Comment: Removed the `sql-server` tag.

Comment: Thank you sir -- sorry about that!

Comment: Out of morbid curiosity what's the execution plan look on that beast?

Comment: the number of joins is not a problem - the problem are the few joins where there is no suitable key to join on, and / or a large number of rows returned i.e. engineConfig and vehicleConfig

Comment: @collapsar Thank you. I'm removing the DISTINCT tag now. I don't suppose you could put what changes you're suggesting into a pastebin? I don't think I completely understand.

Comment: there is no `order by` clause in your query, while you limit the result set to 11 items. this doesn't make sense as the database doesn't guarantee you to return the results in any particular order without explicitly asking it to do so.

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths I appreciate your suggestion, but how can I tell if there is no suitable key. Do you mean the ones that show NULL for the key value?

Comment: @collapsar I appreciate your continued assistance. I removed the DISTINCT qualifier, and added 'ORDER BY sku LIMIT 10' to the bottom of the query.

Comment: why do you limit the result to 10 in the first place ? is this for testing only or do you only need the 'most recent' records (or those satisfying some other constraint) in your results ?

Comment: @collapsar I was limiting it to 10 only to see how fast it'd pull the 10 records. The 'Import_AcesApplication_New' table is gigantic -- it has over 70 million records at the moment, and I didn't want for it to return 70 million records before I see how quickly 10 runs.

Thanks!

Comment: yes - where 'key' is NULL in the 'explain select' and/or where 'rows' is very large.  Just for comparison, if you remove the vehicle config and engine config joins (plus any other joins that were using them) then you should see an orders of magnitude speedup.  This might not solve your problem but it would identify the problem.  As someone said - doing one initial select to get the top 10 followed by a second select to lookup the remaining items might be the best way

Comment: I think the main problem is not the number of joins but the `DISTINCT` that has to be performed after so many tables have been joined. My suggestion would be to convert that to a `GROUP BY` query, after identifying which columns (from which tables) will be used in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query appears to be perfectly laid out.  Your primary table IS the "Import_AcesApplication_New" table, and all the rest are derived lookup tables from the primary.  I had a similar issue with Government grants/contracts queries doing lookup to 20+ tables and the query choked and that was against 15+ million records

By simply adding the keyword

"STRAIGHT_JOIN"

select STRAIGHT_JOIN  [rest of query]

It forced the engine to run the query "in the order you presented" to it.  It might be trying to over analyzed itself on which table has the lowest records, best indexes, etc and working itself backwards by some strange table selection.

Also, edited original query to better show associated links via hierarchy for readability

I would expect all your lookup tables to have indexes on their primary key, but you could also benefit by having covering indexes so the raw data pages per lookup are not necessarily required.

```
Table                       Index suggestion
Import_AcesApplication_New  ( sku, notes, base_vehicle_id, position_id, part_type_id )
BaseVehicle                 ( BaseVehicleID, MakeID, ModelID, YearID )
Make                        ( MakeID, MakeName )
Model                       ( ModelID, modelname )
Positions                   ( PositionID, Position )
Parts                       ( PartTerminologyID, partterminologyname )
Vehicle                     ( BaseVehicleID, SubModelID, VehicleID )
SubModel                    ( SubModelID, SubModelName )
VehicleConfig               ( VehicleID ) -- too many other fields to be practical
EngineConfig                ( EngineConfigID ) -- too many to be practical
EngineBase                  ( EngineBaseID ) -- too many to be practical
EngineDesignation           ( EngineDesignationID, EngineDesignationName )
EngineVIN                   ( EngineVINID, EngineVINName )
Valves                      ( Valvesid, ValvesPerEngine )
FuelDeliveryConfig          ( FuelDeliveryConfigID, FuelDeliveryTypeID, FuelDeliverySubTypeID, FuelSystemControlTypeID, FuelSystemDesignID )
FuelDeliveryType            ( FuelDeliveryTypeID, FuelDeliveryTypeName )
FuelDeliverySubType         ( FuelDeliverySubTypeID, FuelDeliverySubTypeName )
FuelSystemControlType       ( FuelSystemControlTypeID, FuelSystemControlTypeName )
FuelSystemDesign            ( FuelSystemDesignID, FuelSystemDesignName )
Aspiration                  ( AspirationID, AspirationName )
CylinderHeadType            ( CylinderHeadTypeID, CylinderHeadTypeName )
FuelType                    ( FuelTypeID, FuelTypeName )
IgnitionSystemType          ( IgnitionSystemTypeID, IgnitionSystemTypeName )
EngineMfr                   ( MfrID, MfrName )
EngineVersion               ( EngineVersionID, EngineVersion )
PowerOutput                 ( PowerOutputId, HorsePower, KilowattPower )
BedConfig                   ( BedConfigID, BedLengthID, BedTypeID )
BedLength                   ( BedLengthID, BedLength, BedLengthMetric 
BedType                     ( BedTypeID, BedTypeName )
BodyStyleConfig             ( BodyStyleConfigID, BodyNumDoorsID, BodyTypeID )
BodyNumDoors                ( BodyNumDoorsID, BodyNumDoors )
BodyType                    ( BodyTypeID, BodyTypeName )
BrakeConfig                 ( BrakeConfigID, FrontBrakeTypeID, RearBrakeTypeID, BrakeSystemID, BrakeABSID )
BrakeType                   ( BrakeTypeID, BrakeTypeName )
BrakeSystem                 ( BrakeSystemID, BrakeSystemName )
BrakeABS                    ( BrakeABSID, BrakeABSName )
DriveType                   ( DriveTypeID, DriveTypeName )
MfrBodyCode                 ( MfrBodyCodeID, MfrBodyCodeName )
SpringType                  ( SpringTypeID, SpringTypeName )
SteeringConfig              ( SteeringConfigID, SteeringTypeID, SteeringSystemID)  -- see note below indexes via JOIN
SteeringType                ( SteeringTypeID, SteeringTypeName )
SteeringSystem              ( SteeringSystemID, SteeringSystemName )
Transmission                ( TransmissionID, TransmissionBaseID )
TransmissionBase            ( TransmissionBaseID, TransmissionTypeID, TransmissionNumSpeedsID, TransmissionControlTypeID )
TransmissionType            ( TransmissionTypeID, TransmissionTypeName )
TransmissionNumSpeeds       ( TransmissionNumSpeedsID, TransmissionNumSpeeds ) 
TransmissionControlType     ( TransmissionControlTypeID,  ??? )  -- possible description column per note below
TransmissionMfrCode         ( TransmissionMfrCodeID, TransmissionMfrCode )
ElecControlled              ( ElecControlledID, ElecControlled )
Mfr                         ( MfrID, MfrName )
WheelBase                   ( WheelBaseID, WheelBase, WheelBaseMetric )
```

also, while looking at the JOINs to get covering indexes, I noticed the join to the steering config to the steering type was made based on

```
ON SteeringConfig.SteeringConfigID = SteeringType.SteeringTypeID
```

Should this have been...

```
ON SteeringConfig.SteeringTypeID = SteeringType.SteeringTypeID
```

On another item... TransmissionControlType is joined to, but you are not pulling any columns from that in your output query... may have been a slight oversight with so many tables/joins.

These should help significantly for the covering indexes in the query

Comment: Thank you for helping out and providing your own experience with a similar case. I started running the query with your suggestion, and it seems to be moving along now. I'll report back shortly with how long it takes to return those 10 records but it's certainly better than it was (being stuck all night in statistics).

Comment: Good advice on the STRAIGHT_JOIN. I would also suggest checking to ensure that all the keys being joined are indexed. You can troubleshoot extremely long queries like this by adding the joins one at a time until the query performance starts to degrade. Then you will have a better idea of where your bottleneck is.

Comment: @BrianSchroeter, revised to show what I would have with respect to covering indexes, and a finding on a possible bad JOIN too.

Comment: @BrianSchroeter, glad it worked for you, and it would be interesting to know the time for it to run... especially before / after the covering index offerings have been applied.

Comment: @DRapp Thank you so much for all of the help! When creating the indexes, is there a difference in clicking "Index" for each column in phpMyAdmin versus checking them all and clicking index? It's a difference between having multiple indexes or just one with all of the columns -- is one better in this case or always? Screenshot here for further explanation: http://i.imgur.com/1DaAKcA.png

Comment: @BrianSchroeter, it depends on the query.  Typically you would want based on whatever your querying criteria is plus anything that could be a group by in one index (such as covering provided).  This is one index that has ALL the parts.  Check my answer to this question to help understand multiple column indexes for optimizing a query.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460138/mysql-index-usage-query-optimization/20462042#20462042

Comment: @DRapp Hey there! Thank you again for the assistance. I've added all of the cover indexes and ran ANALYZE on the tables. I also adjusted the two errors you outlined in the query (thanks!), but for some reason, it's still running for quite some time. Perhaps it's unavoidable? Right now it's up to 37000 seconds and it's still in 'Sending Data'. What do you think?