# MySQL Optimization of a request

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a join request on 2 tables. I do this request 2 times for pagination. I did one SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS request before.

Table A contains 145000 rows
Table B contains 91000 rows

These are MyIsam tables.

Table A is like this :

```
id        MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED PK
id_b      MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED INDEX
rights    ENUM ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8') INDEX
avail     ENUM ('0', '1', '2', '3') INDEX
del_date  DATE INDEX
... and 40 others fields
```

And these indexes :

```
rights, avail, del_date
id_b, rights, avail, del_date
```

Table B is like this :

```
id        MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED PK
title     VARCHAR(150) INDEX
.. and 47 others fields
```

So here are the requests :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id_b
WHERE
  A.rights NOT IN ('7')
  AND (A.del_date IS NULL OR A.del_date > '2016-02-17')
  AND A.avail NOT IN ('0')
ORDER BY B.title;

SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id_b
WHERE
  A.rights NOT IN ('7')
  AND (A.del_date IS NULL OR A.del_date > '2016-02-17')
  AND A.avail NOT IN ('0')
ORDER BY B.title
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

The first request actually takes 2 seconds and the 2nd 0.3 seconds. Before trying to optimize the max that I can, it sometimes takes 10 seconds or more for the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS request.

Optimization I have done :

- suppress the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and do it with 2 requests.
- the fields rights and avail were TINYINT(4) UNSIGNED, now they are ENUM
- I added these 2 parts indexes **rights, avail, del_date** & **id_b, rights, avail, del_date** to optimize the ORDER BY clause (very good gain)

But now, I notice that (**A.del_date IS NULL OR A.del_date > '2016-02-17'**) is the cause of the slowness.

If I delete all this clause (**A.del_date IS NULL OR A.del_date > '2016-02-17'**) or just **A.del_date IS NULL**, the request is very quick.

Any help will be very very appreciated !

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Answer (score 1):

The first `SELECT`, which has only a `COUNT(*)`, is strange for several reasons...

- The `ORDER BY` is useless, and possibly slows down the query.
- What is the mapping between `A` and `B`?  If it is 1:1, then there is no need to include anything about `B`.  If there are 0 or 1 `B` rows for each `A`, then you need the `JOIN`.  If it is 1:many, then the `COUNT` will be more than the number of rows from `A`; is that what you want?  To fix that, change the `JOIN` into an `EXISTS`.

If you need to keep `B` in the query, add `INDEX(rights, del_date, avail, id_b)` (in any order).
If you do not need to keep `B`, then have add `INDEX(rights, del_date, avail)` (in any order).
In either case, that will be a "covering index" (`EXPLAIN` will say "Using index") and it will run faster.

`OR` is often a performance killer -- it usually eliminates the possibility of using an index.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see if that is the case here.

Please do not present information in sentences; use the actual output or schema specifications.  Things can get lost.

You should consider moving to InnoDB.

If necessary, you should get rid of the "out of nnn items", thereby eliminating the `COUNT(*)` or `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

For the main query, the problem is that the filtering is on one table, but the `ORDER BY` is on another table. This makes optimization either difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having individual column indexes on your "A" table, I would recommend trying a composite index of multiple fields that match your criteria.  This way, the engine does not require loading all the actual page data for ever record to confirm the other parts, but can get only those via the content found in the index.  Then, those that qualify it reads the actual pages of data for the rest of the record.

Looking at your WHERE clause, and since you are using NOT IN for your rights and availability flags, I would have an index on ( del_date, avail, rights )

Your "B" table, I would also have an index on (id, title) for similar reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I wrote, I have 2 parts indexes : rights, avail, del_date & id_b, rights, avail, del_date

Comment: @Amoeba, yes, but due to the NOT IN, I would have the del_date in the FIRST POSITION, then the others. take a look at another post where I clarify indexes and how interpreted.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460138/mysql-index-usage-query-optimization/20462042#20462042

Comment: ok. Did it. The count request now last between 1.2 and 1.6 seconds... A little better. Will read it now.

Comment: I EXPLAIN the query after the change, and MySQL takes this index : id_b, del_date, avail, rights (created long ago) as steted in the KEY column, and not the new one. I deleted the old one, and EXPLAIN tells me NULL in the key column... It doesn't care about this 3 parts index. And the request execution time still 1.2 sec ... Very strange behaviour.

Comment: I deleted the index and added this one : (del_date, id_b, avail, rights) and now, 0.5 seconds !!! Many thanks @DRapp

Comment: @Amoeba, glad it worked, and I am sad that I missed the "id_b" portion of the index for the join.  Also just take a quick check at the top for Help -> Tour for site etiquette... so users know a question is resolved.